# Serializing array of JSON objects from JSON response

Tags: c#, json

I have a json response that looks like this:

```
"corps":
[
{
"id": "1007",
"company_id": "1007",
"org_name": "My organization 1",
"org_addr1": "123 W. 1234 S.",
"org_addr2": "",
},
{
"id": "1008",
"org_name": "My organization 2",
"org_addr1": "123 W. 1234 S.",
"org_addr2": "",
}
]
```

I have successfully gotten a single response into my HCO object properly using:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(HCO));
HCO Company = (HCO)serializer.ReadObject(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
```

This works well, but I'm trying to get all elements under corps. So I thought of trying something like this:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(HCO));
HCO element = (HCO)serializer.ReadObject(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
Companies.Add(element);
```

But this simply doesn't work. How do I parse the json result and then serialize each element in the response?

HCO Class:

```
public class HCO
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int comapny_id { get; set; }
        public string org_name { get; set; }
        public string org_addr1 { get; set; }
        public string org_addr2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: CAn you show what HCO looks like

Comment: `Companies.AddRange(Company.corps)`

Comment: @L.B I don't have corps type under my HCO. Updated question to include sample HCO

Comment: Kyle, then how would your first code work? (As you say *"This works well"*) Your Json is not of type HCO. It is an object where its `coprs` property is a List of HCO.

Comment: The first code was working when their was no array (i.e. only one element returned by the json server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap up the HCO class in a Response like this:

```
public class HCOResponse
{
    public List<HCO> corps {get; set;}
}
```

And then try to deserialize the json using DataContractJsonSerializer like this:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(HCOResponse));
Companies = (HCOResponse)serializer.ReadObject(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
```

Hope it helps.

EDIT: (from feedback)

```
HCOResponse hco_resp = (HCOResponse)serializer.ReadObject(response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
Companies = hco_resp.corps;
```

Comment: Ok I gave this a shot but it said it could not convert HCOResponse to a generic list.

Comment: Let me understand the situation, you wrote this: Companies.Add(element); since element is a HCO instance, could you let me know what type is the object Companies? There might be a cast error instead of a serialize error in my answer.

Comment: Let's see it appears as though I had to change Companies to type HCOResponse instead of List<HCO> and it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: I updated my answer to asign companies HCOResponse.corps, glad I could help.